# Is it possible to set the result value of 'None < None' to False in python?

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading, nonetype

I want to get that result when I write only `None < None` in the editor without using `try`, `except`. Of course, I tried to redefine the `__lt__` function of `None`, but an error occurred. Is there any good way?

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. without context, that's an odd request, tbh. maybe a  (sub)class with `__lt__()` overridden?

Comment: Can you share the code of your `__lt__` redefinition, along with the error?

Answer (score 0):

hi and thanks for answering. I know it's odd to compare 'None' and 'None'. Nevertheless, a result value (True or False) is required.

Take a look at the example code below

```
if func1() < func2():
    ~~~~
```

In this case, if either func1() or func2() has None, you can add code that handles whether one of them is None.

```
if func1() and func2():
    if func1() < func2():
        ~~~~
```

However, it is very cumbersome to add these conditional statements one by one every time a comparison statement is encountered in the code I am working on (at least 1 million lines exceed).

So, if there is even one None in the comparison statement, I want to get the result value (If None is compared, it is treated as False) so that the code inside the if is not executed.

And as mechanical_meat said 'lt' means `__lt__()`